# Display concatenated string in a text box

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, concatenation

I am attempting to build a button calculator. So, a user pressed a button marked "0", the text box displays 0. The challenge I'm running into is when a user would press the 0 button twice ("00") or press 1 and then 0. ("10.")

I have an event set up for each number button. My idea was to have a universal variable called runningAnswer to store a running tally of concatenating answers. I then have a button string, and a "holder" string, since I can't append the runningAnswer string with the button string.

The problem I'm running into is I have to initiate the holder string. I can get the text box to display the "0" with my method, but each time I press it, the runningAnswer just stores the first "0", because the holder string is re-setting itself.

I apologize if this is a really simple question. I'm just feeling really lost about how to build this kind of app.

```
- (IBAction)btn0:(id)sender {
    NSString* zero =@"0";
    NSString* holder= @"";
    runningAnswer=[holder stringByAppendingString:zero];
    self.txtResult.text = runningAnswer;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to declare **holder** string outside your function

```
NSString *holder = @"";
```

and inside your function

```
holder = [holder stringByAppendingString:zero];
self.txtResult.text = holder;
```

Comment: That's what I thought too but declaring it outside the method results in a nil value when I step into it. I can't figure why that is...

Comment: @MichelleFarley When I say outside the method, I mean: declare the variable in your class, and initialize it somewhere else (int the `init` method, for example)

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of the holder and just do

```
runningAnswer = [runningAnswer stringByAppendingString:zero];
```

And make sure running answer is initialized in init like:

```
- (id)init
{
  self = [super init];
  if (self) {
    runningAnswer = @"";
  }
  return self;
}
```